# Retrieve username and invite friends on django-facebook

Tags: django, facebook, django-facebook

I followed the instructions to install Django-facebook into my site to allow users to register, login, invite friends and share stuff on my site. I could easily register users to my site using their facebook accounts. However, i'm very confused on how to log them out, retrieve the facebook username of users, and how to integrate the mutliselect friends invite thing.

Here is mys settings.py file

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django_facebook.context_processors.facebook',
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.core.context_processors.debug',
'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
'django.core.context_processors.media',
'django.core.context_processors.static',
'django.core.context_processors.tz',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
 )

 AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'django_facebook.auth_backends.FacebookBackend',
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
 )

 AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "appname.UserProfile"

FACEBOOK_APP_ID = "<myappID>"
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET ="<myappsecretkey>"
```

In my models.py, I created a custom user profile as follow :

```
# User model
class UserProfile(FacebookProfileModel):
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
playedHours = models.FloatField(default = 0)



playedSongs = models.ManyToManyField(Song, blank=True, null = True)
invitedFriends = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank = True, null = True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.facebook_name



 from django.db.models.signals import post_save
 from django.dispatch import receiver

 @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
 def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  """Create a matching profile whenever a user object is created."""
  if created: 
    profile, new = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

In the urls.py i added these two lines and I have no idea what they do tbh :

```
(r'^facebook/', include('django_facebook.urls')),
(r'^accounts/', include('django_facebook.auth_urls')),
```

What I want to achieve exactly is, once users sign up with facebook, i want to get their name and profile picture, and allow them to invite their friends.

I've been searching for (up-to-date) tutorials and I failed miserably at it.
Any help is very appreciated !!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For logging them out, auth_logout "/logout/" url might help.

Regarding Facebook_name, take a look at FacebookProfileModel:
facebook_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

So you can access it via profile_object.facebook_name.